# Getting warning_ invalid argument supplied for foreach in my php/jquery script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, warnings

Hello wise stackoverflow users

I am currently working on a private messaging system in PHP, and i am stuck at making a function to delete multiple selected messages. As it is right now, it is working but i get the warning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/PM/delete.php on line 7
```

I use jquery to sent the data to another php file called delete.php.
First thing first, my checkboxes look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="message_checkbox" name="pms[]" value="<? echo $loadData['id']; ?>" id="<? echo $loadData['id']; ?>">
```

And my jquery script look like the following:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.delete").click(function(){
        var message = new Array();
        $("input[@name='pms[]']:checked").each(function() {
            message.push($(this).val());
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'PM/delete.php',
            data: { id: message },
            success: function(html) {
                alert("all done");
            }
        });
    })
})
</script>
```

My delete.php looks like the following:

```
<?php ob_start();
include("../config.php");

$rows2del = $_POST["id"];

foreach($rows2del as $id) /* Line 7*/
{
        mysql_query("UPDATE user_pm SET reciev_deleted = '1' WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
}   
?>
```

Anyone who can tell me what i am doing wrong?

*Note: Im very new in the jquery and javascript field!*

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Invalid argument supplied to foreach means that `$rows2del` is not an array or iteratable object.  try `var_dump($rows2del);` and see what the value is.

Comment: Are you sure $rows2del is actually an array? You may want to log something like print_r($_POST) to see what's in it. If you're only posting one item to PHP, it may treat whatever you post onto it as just a single parameter.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your Javascript.  The error message points to your PHP foreach statement.

Comment: Also, as the other commenters say use mysqli or PDO... This script is vulnerable to SQL injection as written and a prepared statement would fix that. Also Mysql_*() functions are deprecated!

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I did not know that i should use mysqli or PDO, so I will read something about that, thanks for the links.. If i use var_dump($rows2del); I get a big fat "NULL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong `$("input[@name='pms[]']:checked")` there is no `@name` attribute you might be thinking about xpath. It should just be `$("input[name='pms[]']:checked")`

So you're passing an empty array here `data: { id: message },` which will not add the `id` parameter to you post request, therefore `$_POST["id"];` will be empty.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
I guess my array is still empty because it wirtes NULL when I use var_dump($rows2del);.
Eventhough I removed the @. Any suggestion to why it is empty?

Comment: At least one of your checkboxes need to be checked for `$_POST["id"]` to have a value in it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as json string in a post variable then json decode on the server side.

```
 this is the correct way to push an value inside an json object array
 message.push({id: $(this).val()});

 pass it as string in the post
 data: 'message='+JSON.stringify(message),
```